# XAMPP dvwa: The requested URL was not found on this server

Tags: mysql, apache, xampp

Im getting this error when xampp (the server runs, but cannot start DVWA)

The requested URL was not found on this server.

Apache/2.4.54 (Win64) OpenSSL/1.1.1p PHP/7.4.30 Server at localhost Port 80

Heres the control panel:
[image: XAMPP Control Panel]

Im typing it using url: http://localhost/dvwa/setup.php

Let me know what can be done